# What is the best way for comparing the diagnostic performance of sequential testing? Log regression? Compare ROC?

Tags: multiple-regression, diagnostic

I have two index tests, Test A and Test B, both of which have been studied in participants. Every participant also underwent the reference standard.
I've found that Test A and Test B perform equally well against the reference standard in terms of accuracy, ROC curves, and other measures.

I now want to determine if adding the information provided by Test B enhances the predictive capacity beyond the results of Test A alone.

I am considering conducting a logistic regression, starting with a model using only Test A, and then a second model that incorporates both Test A and Test B. I intend to compare the performance of these models using a likelihood ratio test (LRT).

Is this a statistically sound approach? Can I conclusively state that Test B does not enhance the classification power of the model if added to Test A?
Is there any other more accepted way to approach this issue?

Thank you in advance.